# Windows 2008, Configure Firewall to "Ask"

Tags: windows, internet, firewall, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to configure the firewall in windows (2008 R2 SP1) to "ask" whether it should allow a programm access to the internet? Or do I need some 3rd-party software for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it on a per program basis, but not as an outbound firewall for anything wanting to leave the PC.

Free edition allows some Windows components by default and you cannot block them, but plus edition allows you to.

http://www.sphinx-soft.com/Vista/order.html